# Sublime Text 3 Ruler

Tags: sublimetext3

I tried to add a ruler through View>Ruler but it adds to the current file only.
How to make a specific ruler with the size of 79 characters in sublime and make it appear in every file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a ruler appear in every file, then go to `Preferences: Settings` from the command palette and add the setting `"rulers": [79]` to your user preferences. This will make the ruler appear at column 79 for every file.

The reason why `View -> Ruler -> <Some value>` applies only for the current file is because, behind the scenes, it uses a command called `set_setting`, which sets the given setting (here it's `rulers`) and it's value only for the current view (Just try to apply a ruler value to a file using `View -> Ruler`, close the file, open it again and see that it doesn't persist. It's just temporary). Hence, the rulers value is not applied to any other file